# Python Constructor not showing anything on IDE

Tags: python

Trying to create a class constructor but for some reason im failing misarably when testing..

```
class Person(object):
    name=""
    age=0
    city=""

    def __init__ (self,name,age,city):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.city=city        

    #Just testing
    def AddPerson(Person):
        person1 = Person()
        person1.name="test"
        person1.age=1
        person1.city="here"
        print(person1)
```

Process finished with exit code 0.
Nothing happening. I know this is basic but maybe im not seeing something here. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

If that's all your code, then you're not instantiating any object.  Add this to your code ( but on the left, **not** in your class):

```
p = Person("Fernando", 99, "City")
print(p.age)
print(p.name)
print(p.city)
```

And your output should be:

```
99
Fernando
City
```

You defined a class, but it doesn't do anything until you create an instance of it as shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__ (self,name,age,city):
    self.name=name
    self.age=age
    self.city=city        

#Just testing
def AddPerson(Person):
    person1 = Person()
    person1.name="test"
    person1.age=1
    person1.city="here"
    print(person1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p_add = Person('asdf', 20 ,'NYC')
    print (p_add.name,p_add.age, p_add.city)`
```

You do not call a function in the class, so your result is exit0